# Making a checkbox Ui with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if I made any "posting" mistakes.

I am using Google Apps Script for the project I am doing, because I am interacting with Google Docs and Google sheets. Google Script has a deprecated Ui Service, which is very frustrating to me.

So far, I have written a JavaScript program that parses through the "table of contents" part of a Google Doc, and retrieves the items I wanted. (If the table of content is changed, then the items retrieved might be different too.) Now, my intention is to make a checkbox that uses all the items that I retrieved from the table of contents as its options, and after users choosing and clicking "submit" button, a new Google Sheet would be generated. Of course I will operate on that new Google Sheet, but I want to stick with this problem first.

I did look up HTML Service, a Ui recommended by Google Script, but I don't know too much about HTML. What is most difficult is that if I use HTML to make the checkbox, how am I supposed to get all the items I parsed from the JavaScript passed into the HTML file, check which options are checked, and then get checked options passed back to the JavaScript so that I can do further operation? Is it even possible? Or am I having a misconception?

What I have so far:

```
//custom menu
function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Export Checksheets', 'customMenu')
  .addToUi();
}

//parse the table of contents
function readFile() 
{
  var options = [];

  var testDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var file = testDoc.getBody();
  var tableOfCon = DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS;

  var searchRes = file.findElement(tableOfCon);

  //If the element exists
  if (searchRes)
  {
    var TC = searchRes.getElement().asTableOfContents();
    var numChild = TC.getNumChildren();

    for (var i=0; i < numChild; i++) 
    {
      var info = {};
      var TCItem = TC.getChild(i).asParagraph();
      var TCItemText = TCItem.getChild(0).asText();
      var TCItemAttrs = TCItemText.getAttributes();   //for future usage

      //get all the options
      if (!TCItemText.isBold())
      {
        options.push(TCItem.getText());
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(options);    //which successfully displays the items retrieved
}

//linked to the HTML file
function customMenu()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  html.setHeight(350).setWidth(280);
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Hello!');
}
```

My HTML file only has a little code that displays some message when the custom menu is chosen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is some documentation that shows an example of submitting a form [HTML Service - Client to Server Communications - Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: @SandyGood I took an alternative method, but still thank you very much for answering!